# how to fix ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE error in azure web app deployment using VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service

I am using VSTS pipeline to deploy asp.net core 2.2 MVC to azure web app.
The last step which is deploy to azure fails - please see the error below:

> ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
>   2019-01-08T21:39:47.3810424Z ##[error]Error Code:
>   ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE More Information: Could not connect to
>   the remote computer ("our website url"). On the remote computer, make
>   sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web
>   Management Service") is started.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
>   Error: Unable to connect to the remote server Error: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond ????:443

I even tried to Take App Offline but no luck:

[image]

However, it works fine if I publish the web app through Visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the subscription we were using has a firewall in place. So there was no way to get into firewall by even doing things like adding "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM" = false in the app setting of web service.

The only solution we could think of was to create an agent inside a VM sitting inside the same firewall.

Comment: i have the same issue but for me the visual studio publish already does not work even with `"WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM" = false`.

Comment: The reason for us it didn't work was because of proxy. Our architects created all web services and other things inside a proxy. Therefore the default build agent couldn't get access to the resources. What we have done was to set up a build agent inside the proxy so it could freely get access to our service. Check if it is like your case

Comment: Yes i saw that but there is no proxy in my case. Anyway i used a different approach and this worked for now.

Comment: Awesome. could you please share your solution.

Comment: hi, I somewhat cheated. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203359/azure-web-app-with-net-core-3-0-fails-cant-find-microsoft-aspnetcore-app/61084453#61084453).

Answer (score 0):

Recreate web app in Azure Portal -> Make sure target framework selected correctly.

I had accidentally set this to docker previously during my web app setup in the portal and this error was produced as well. I was using a MVC .NET 4.7 project and trying to use web deploy.

Hopefully this helps someone who has perhaps set up their web app incorrectly in the azure portal.

Comment: but, this cannot be the case because, the original poster is able to deploy the app manually. If the issue is app configuration, direct deployment would fail too.