# Azure web app with .NET Core 3.0 fails: Can't find Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

We are trying to deploy our web app after upgrading to .NET Core 3.0, but it keeps getting the "service unavailable" message. If we try to run `dotnet` from Kudu (`dotnet webapp.dll`) we get the following error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.10 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.1.12 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.1.13 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.2.5 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.2.6 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.2.7 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The .NET Core frameworks can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

We tried to install .NET Core 3.0 with [Microsoft's guide for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-30-to-azure-app-service), but with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say you tried to install .net core 3.0 but had no success, are you meaning you were able to install the extension but it didn't fix the problem? 

We are running a .net core 3.0 web app fine in azure using the guide provided above. We had to do what @David_D mentioned below (create a SCD) but only for our web job.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3.0 is supported now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem. Azure App Service does not currently support Net Core 3.

The temporary workaround is to build a self contained app from Visual Studio through the publish tool. You can change it from Framework Dependent to Self Contained in the publishing settings. Simply deploy that to Azure.

We also tried to use our DevOps pipelines to do this, but couldn't work out how to do a self contained build and as Azure will hopefully support Net Core 3 soon, the publish works fine for now.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, one can add 3.0 via Extensions of the App Service.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is no longer an issue due to Azure App Service now supporting .Net Core 3, as does DevOps Pipelines.

Comment: Whilst it says it supports it on the azure portal, I still get this error when is set to netcore 3.0

Comment: I was getting this until I removed Identity from my test app.  It was nice to know I could get it working but Identity is a required feature for this project.

Comment: @JussiPalo doesn't work even via Extensions of the App Service, I got same issue!!! For now David's answer is the right one! I spent one day to fix this issue unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 9):

You can keep track on the latest releases on the [ASP.NET Core on App Service Dashboard](https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I'll bookmark it to see when I can stop publishing as a self-contained app. Is there anywhere that shows a road map of when they will start rolling out? Because as of right now EVERY zone shows still on 2.2. Would've thought MS would be hosting their own platform at least in trial in a zone or two after release. We've had preview releases for months now.

Comment: No roadmap, but apparently they "expect global deployment to complete by October 11th". https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/204

Comment: I was looking for a link like this for a while. serious question: where did you even find it?

Comment: I found it on a discussion thread on one of the https://learn.microsoft.com/ sites. Unfortunately I'm not able to re-find again.

Comment: Looks like ASP.NET Core 3.0 is supported now. I published an Azure web app using ASP.NET Core today without resorting to "self-contained app" and it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can add .net core 3.0 x86/ 64 framework using Azure app service extension (open app service -> extensions). Then publish .net core 3.0 app.

Comment: Extensions is greyed out. Any ideas what the resolution to this is?

Comment: Doesn't work! using the extensions, the only solution for now is @David's answer use Visual Studio Publish tool.

Answer (score 1):

Now Azure supports .NET core 3.0 check out my article on how to publish without self contained app.

https://link.medium.com/U2PhGVLrJ0

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core 3.0 is now available

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to an incorrect web.config. When changing to self-contained application you have to modify the aspNetCore-part of your web.config.

New web.config

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\[your].exe"
stdoutLogEnabled="false"
stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"/>
```

Old web.config

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
arguments=".\[your].dll" 
stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying .net core 3.1 blazor server app to app service linux and it failed with same error. So I deployed it to windows .net core 3.0 web app and it worked as self-contained and framework-dependent (windows x86) deployment. Apparently .net core 3.1 runtime is also installed on these servers. But haven't checked.